# Replace invalid decimal points in string based math equation Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I am working on an alternative method for validating user input on an iOS calculator app. I have already written code that would turn string example: "9*++8" > "9+8". The code accepts the last operator that the user inputs and removes the rest. I understand this is probably not the most efficient method for input validation, but I am rolling with it and trying to figure it out.

My issue is when a user would input something like "9.9.9+9.9". Ideally I would like to remove all decimals that come after the first appearance of a decimal and then restart this logic every time a mathematical operator (+,-,* etc) is introduced.

Looking for something that would give me I/O of "9.9.9+9.9" > "9.99+9.9"

Comment: 9.9.9 is not a valid value. you should just throw an error. Another option is to remove all periods after the first one found in your value

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve such a problem.

One way to tackle this problem is to define your own grammar and parse your input as a word of this grammar. Tools to achieve this are yacc, ANTLR and similar. But I assume you were looking for a simpler solution.

Another way is to define a suitable regular expression that matches all extra decimals and remove those.

But for such a special case as in your description, you might be able to solve it in a straightforward iteration over the string. Pseudocode below:

```
isbehindDecimal = false
tokens = []
digits = ““
for character in string{
  if character == “.” {
     if isbehindDecimal { continue } // Skipt extra decimals
     isbehindDecimal = true
     tokens.append(character)
     tokens.append(digits) // Add digits before the decimal
     digits = ““
  } else if (character is an operator) {
     isbehinddecimal = false
     if (tokens.last() is an operator) {
         replace last element of tokens with operator
     } else {
         tokens.append(character)
         tokens.append(digits) // Add digits before the operator
         digits = ““
     }
  } else if (character is a digit) {
     digits.append(character)
  }

}

tokens.append(digits) // Number that ends the string
```

In the end, the tokens array would contain everything that you are interested in. But you would still need to sanitize / parse the input. If your input rules become more and more complicated, this will soon become messy and hard to handle. Then its time to define your own grammar.